# Cannot GET routes other than "/" express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a web app with the MVC pattern and express in node.js. This is my project structure:
[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOZpT.png)

app.js:

```
let express = require("express");
let hbs = require("hbs");
let app = express();

let indexController = require("./controllers/indexController");
let loginController = require("./controllers/loginController");

app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.use('/login', loginController);
app.use('/', indexController);

app.listen(3000);
```

loginController.js:

```
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that I can access the index page ("/") but not the login page ("/login") even when the code for both is almost identical.

Here's the code of indexController.js:

```
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't really know what's happening, I'm kinda new to express and MVC and couldn't find anything online, please help :)

Comment: Replace `router.get('/login', (req, res) => {` with `router.get('/', (req, res) => {`, because you have already specified path in `app.js`.

Comment: @YuriyYakym damn I didn't notice, thanks a lot.

Comment: everything you need to know https://dev.to/santypk4/bulletproof-node-js-project-architecture-4epf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'login' twice. The first one is enough in `app.use('/login', loginController);` Inside, you can remove the other

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});
```